# showcase smiles in content - no smile appears

Tags: php

I am in the process of making such on the website that there will be smiles while writing some can define the character on the page. that's how I've tried to do like this:

```
                echo $tekst;

                $smiles = array(
                  ':)'  => 'devil.png',
                  '>:)'  => 'devil.png',
                  'x('  => 'angry.png',
                  ';-)' => 'wink.png'
                );
                foreach($smiles as $key => $img) {
                    $msg = str_replace($key, "<img src=\"emotions/'.$img.'\" height=\"18\" width=\"18\" />", $msg);
                }
                echo $msg;
```

It is such that there will be nothing appears on the page at all.

The problem is such that it will not display the images from the smiles are.

Comment: Are the images in current directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is the correct code:

```
$msg = 'Hello world :)!';

$smiles = array(
  ':)'  => 'devil.png',
  '>:)'  => 'devil.png',
  'x('  => 'angry.png',
  ';-)' => 'wink.png'
);

foreach($smiles as $key => $img) {
  $msg = str_replace($key, '<img src="emotions/'.$img.'" height="18" width="18" />', $msg);
}

echo $msg;
```

Try to avoid double-quoted strings in PHP, they tend to be messier and unmaintainable.

In fact, a better way of doing that part would be:

```
foreach($smiles as $key => $img) {
  $img = sprintf('<img src="emotions/%s" height="18" width="18" />', $img);
  $msg = str_replace($key, $img, $msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some extra single quotes. As your code is currently, the output is:

```
Input: Hello :) world
Hello <img src="emotions/'.devil.png.'" height="18" width="18" /> world
```

If you change this line:

```
$msg = str_replace($key, "<img src=\"emotions/$img\" height=\"18\" width=\"18\" />", $msg);
```

You get the correct output:

```
Hello <img src="emotions/devil.png" height="18" width="18" /> world
```

This works because PHP performs variable interpolation when using double quotes on a string. See [this page in the PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The following needs to be changed

```
$msg = str_replace($key, "<img src=\"emotions/'.$img.'\" height=\"18\" width=\"18\" />", $msg);
                                              ^^    ^^
```

which produces `<img src="emotions/'.devil.png.'" height="18" width="18" />`

To:

```
$msg = str_replace($key, "<img src=\"emotions/$img\" height=\"18\" width=\"18\" />", $msg);
```

produces `<img src="emotions/devil.png" height="18" width="18" />`

You should always check your `view-source` to see what's being produced or do a `var_dump`